# ASP.NET MVC DotNetOpenAuth get ReturnURL after Authenticate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

When I call my authenticate, I am passing the Return Url from from the Query String.  When the Open Id provider redirects back to the same Action Result, the Return Url parameter is null.  What is the best way to persist this across the call?

Are people storing the local Return Url in the session?  Below is the method in question.

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Authenticate(string returnUrl)
    {
        openId = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

        IAuthenticationResponse response = openId.GetResponse();

        if (response == null)
        {
            Identifier id;
            if (Identifier.TryParse(Request.Form["openid_identifier"], out id))
            {
                try
                {
                    // at this point we have a return Url
                    return openId.CreateRequest(id).RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
                }
                catch (ProtocolException pex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", pex.Message);
                    return View("LogOn");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Identifier");
                return View("LogOn");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            switch (response.Status)
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(response.ClaimedIdentifier, true);
                    // at this point return URL is null

                    var fetch = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
                    string email = string.Empty;
                    if (fetch != null)
                        email = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                    {
                        var test = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(User.Identity.Name, false);
                        var url = AppHelper.GenerateReturnURL(Request, returnUrl);
                        return Redirect(url);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Canceled at provider");
                    return View("LogOn");
                case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", response.Exception.Message);
                    return View("LogOn");
            }
        }

        return View("LogOn");
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the returnUrl value was populated when your form was initially posted to your Authenticate action Before any calls to the OpenID provider?

Comment: positive.  it is filled with /Admin as i would expect from the Query String.  When it gets returned back to the same action, it is null.  Would you expect it to remain after the OpenID provider call?

Comment: Is the returnUrl submitted as the URL query string rather than a field post? e.g. <form action="/account/authenticate?returnurl=%2Findex">, if it was then I would expect it to be repopulated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
                        //add returnURL as a callback argument
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                        request.AddCallbackArguments("returnUrl", returnUrl);
```

Comment: Yes, this is a reasonable approach to take.